# Clojure apply transform function to values of a map

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap, reducers

Let's say I have a map :

```
 {:top 2.8421709430404007E-14, :left 0, :down 240, :right 400N}
```

How can I iterate over it to convert everything into integers ?

```
 {:top 0, :left 0, :down 240, :right 400}
```

An obvious solution would be :

```
 {:top (:top m), :left (:left m), :down (:down m), :right (:right m)}
```

but it feels *very* repetitive.

I feel a reducing function could do nicely here, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a `map` over the entries could be another way:

```
(into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [k (int v)]) m))
;; {:top 0, :left 0, :down 240, :right 400}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use [`reduce-kv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv):

```
(reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (int %3)) {} {:top 2.8421709430404007E-14, :left 0, :down 240, :right 400N})
;;=>{:down 240, :left 0, :right 400, :top 0}
```

*Edit :* [`algo.generic.fmap`](https://clojure.github.io/algo.generic/clojure.algo.generic.functor-api.html#clojure.algo.generic.functor/fmap) looks like it would work as well.

*Edit bis :*
Thanks to @Andre for mentioning that a `map-vals` function exists in both `weavejester/medley` or `prismatic/plumbing`.

From [`medley`](https://github.com/weavejester/medley/blob/master/src/medley/core.cljc#L60) :

```
(defn map-vals
  "Maps a function over the values of an associative collection."
  [f coll]
  (reduce-map (fn [xf] (fn [m k v] (xf m k (f v)))) coll))
```

From [`plumbing`](https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing/blob/master/src/plumbing/core.cljx#L68) :

```
(defn map-vals
  "Build map k -> (f v) for [k v] in map, preserving the initial type"
  [f m]
  (cond
   (sorted? m)
   (reduce-kv (fn [out-m k v] (assoc out-m k (f v))) (sorted-map) m)
   (map? m)
   (persistent! (reduce-kv (fn [out-m k v] (assoc! out-m k (f v))) (transient {}) m))
   :else
   (for-map [[k v] m] k (f v))))
```

Comment: Just FYI: Many many people use (or create) a `map-vals` function. For instance `weavejester/medley` or `prismatic/plumbing` both have these with some performance benefits using transients.

Comment: @Andre Thanks, if you want to put that as an answer (with links/code like https://github.com/weavejester/medley/blob/master/src/medley/core.cljc#L60 ) I'd hapilly accept. I also found https://clojure.github.io/algo.generic/clojure.algo.generic.functor-api.html#clojure.algo.generic.functor/fmap

Comment: Your answer is fine, just add the examples if you want.